# xslt - compare local and global variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

how can I make a comparation of two value which one inside for-each tag and a variable outside for-each tag like example below

```
<xsl:variable name="uid" >
    <xsl:value-of select="/ctas/output/uid" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="/ctas/user/row">
    <xsl:variable name="user_uid" select="user_uid" />
    <xsl:if test="$user_uid &ne; $uid" >
        //do something
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What entity reference did you bind `&ne;` to? Typically, you would use `=`, `!=`, `not()` etc. Creating a DTD just for replacing `!=` with a cryptic entity reference seems a bit odd to me (and, without it, it is not well-formed XML, so with every copy and paste you will have to add the DTD section too).

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to write

```
<xsl:variable name="uid" >
    <xsl:value-of select="/ctas/output/uid" />
</xsl:variable>
```

simply as

```
<xsl:variable name="uid" select="/ctas/output/uid" />
```

as that selects the node(s) in the input and then to use the variable in a predicate, as in

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ctas/user/row[not(user_uid = $uid)]">...</xsl:for-each>
```

For efficiency such cross-references are often optimized with a key:

```
<xsl:key name="uid" match="ctas/output" use="uid"/>
```

and then

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ctas/user/row[not(key('uid', user_uid))]">...</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: It seem not very clear. In your case some rows will be absent. I just want to add "text A" when user_uid = $uid and "text B" in the other case